# Payment SDK's with Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have never dealt with payment SDK's before. I want to implement Stripe into my app to handle in-app payments, but implementing this may take some time and quite a bit of trial and error.

The issue I am facing is that Firebase requires either the Spark or Blaze plan in order to implement these into the app. But, I do not want to pay for the plans until I am ready to fully launch my app. Is there a good way to test out payment SDK's in Firebase without paying for a plan?

I know that the Blaze plan is pay-as-you-go, but I am hesitant to get the plan now as I am sure exactly how much it would be costing me on a monthly basis while I am just testing things out.

Thanks.

Comment: You are highly unlikely to exceed the free limits for Cloud Functions during development, unless you make some terrible mistakes. The pricing page will tell you the limits.  https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that to integrate 3rd party systems into a Firebase project you have to upgrade to a paid plan. The Blaze plan is the Flame + pay as you go. So if you are not hitting your free limits per month (which if you're the only tester, it is highly unlikely), your cost will just be the cost of the Flame plane, or $25/month (at time of writing).

To test, you can [locally run your Cloud functions using the Firebase shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator). That will confirm them working before you deploy to the GCP servers. Once you have your pay plan setup, just do a regular deploy and it should all work correctly. You will of course need some integration testing based on what apps you are using (web/ios/android).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could run Cloud functions locally. I will give this a try